# iPhone Maps App 'Location Square'

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps, mapkit

In the iPhone Maps application, you get a sort of 'location square' when you tap the disclosure arrow on a dropped pin, like this:

[image]

I've seen a few other apps have this. How would I implement this? I haven't found anything specific in MapKit for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented something similar by simply passing the pin coordinates to the details view, creating an MKMapView with a CGFrame of your choice and adding a pin to it. Because the map is likely to be cached anyway (from the previous view) you will get it loaded straight away.

Comment: To have something like that, I assume that it's placed *above* the actual UITableView, and then some magical graphics stuff is applied to give it the border and the magical rounded corners and small pin?

Comment: add it to the table view header otherwise it won't scroll with the table. For the rounded corners, something like this should work `myMapView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;`, Similar for the border -  `myMapView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;`. Please note you need to add the Quartz framework to your project for this to work. Check the documentation for more details :)

Comment: Awesome. phooze's answer above gave me the correct things to apply to my image cell. I was wondering, wouldn't it be easier to just make the view that size, and then copy it's layer or something into the image cell layer?

Answer (score 1):

Rog has the right idea with the map, I'll just add part he left out inre: the rounded corners (you've indicated in the comments that you're looking for that as well).

Rounded corners comes for free with a lot of UIView stuff.  This is code we put on UITableViewCell items to get a similar effect:

```
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely need this code for this. Thanks a lot!